# Add scroll-lock button to JScrollBar

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar, scroll-lock

## Background

Looking to add a scroll-lock button to the corner of `JScrollPane` without obscuring the view port contents. The following image shows a `JScrollPane` wrapped in a `SwingNode` within a JavaFX application:

[image: Actual]

The lower-right corner shows a button with a lock icon that may be toggled, which is the desired result:

[image: Final]

Notice how the content at the very bottom of the view port---the portion beside the lock button---is visible. (Clicking the button will simulate pressing the scroll-lock button on the keyboard. Having a scroll-lock button at the top is perfectly fine, if that's any easier.)

## Problem

The [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) API shows the following image:

[image: JScrollPane]

Enabling the corner component also seems to require adding a column header. The addition of the header obscures part of the view port, in direct proportion to the scroll-lock button height. Here's a screenshot showing the visible column header, which hides part of the document:

[image: Obscured output]

## Ideas

I've tried making the header view panel transparent, to no avail.

## Code

The relevant code within the `SwingNode`:

```java
// FlyingSaucer subclass
mView = new HtmlPanel(); 
mScrollPane = new JScrollPane( mView );
setContent( mScrollPane );

final var lock = new JButton( "X" );
mScrollPane.setCorner( UPPER_TRAILING_CORNER, lock );
mScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );

final var header = new JPanel();
header.setPreferredSize(
  new Dimension( 12, lock.getPreferredSize().height ) );
header.setOpaque( false );
header.setBackground( new Color( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) );
mScrollPane.setColumnHeaderView( header );
```

See [camickr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17091949/59087) for another example.

## Question

How would you add a button to `JScrollPane`'s bottom (or top) corner such that no view port content is obscured?

## Related

- [How to make a corner component always visible in a JScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17088671/59087)

Comment: So if the corner components are ruled out, would it make sense to provide a custom scrollbar component that allows rendering the scroll lock? I guess the scroll lock functionality is connected to scrolling anyway, so you could create a 'LockableScrollbar'.

Comment: If you are willing to always display the horizontal scrollbar as well, then you will always have a space in the bottom, right corner for a corner component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using "wrapper" panels to achieve you desired layout. Something like:

```
JButton scrollLock = new JButton("...");

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(...);
JScrollBar verticalBar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();

JPanel verticalPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
verticalPanel.add(verticalBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
verticalPanel.add(scrollLock, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
wrapper.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
wrapper.add(verticalPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

setContent(wrapper);
```

Comment: If you are adding a JButton you can use the `setMargin(...)` method to remove extra space around your text/icon. The width of the button will control the width of the scroll bar.